# Change SessionEndedRequest handler response in Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I want to add the handler for `SessionEndedRequest` and change message for `sorry, I'm having trouble accessing your {} skills right now intent name in Alexa` I am using nodeJs SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [can't do that](https://developer.amazon.com/it/docs/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/develop-your-first-skill.html#sessionendedrequest-handler)

You can add a `SessionEndedRequest` handler but, as mentioned in the docs, you can't change the message